# Convert specific query into JPQL or Criteria Builder query

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpql, hibernate-criteria

Here is the code for 2 entities (it generates three tables in the database). A `Book` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Author> authors;
}
```

An `Author` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Author {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;
}
```

I'm trying to find books by the list of authors. Here is a sql query:

```
select book.id, ARRAY_AGG(author.name)
from book 
join book_authors ba on book.id=ba.book_id 
join author on ba.authors_id=author.id
group by book.id
having  ARRAY_AGG(distinct author.name order by author.name)=ARRAY['a1', 'a2']::varchar[]
```

`['a1', 'a2']` is a list of book authors, it must be passed as a parameter. The idea is to aggregate authors and then compare them with the list of passed parameters.

How to rewrite this SQL-query into either a JPQL or CriteriaBuilder query?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Query("select distinct b from Book b join b.authors a where a.name in(:names)")
List<Book> findByAuthorsNames(@Param("names") List<String> names)
```

If you want to fetch `b.authors` use `join fetch` instead of `join`

Comment: So easy? Great!

Comment: Although no, in this case if we have [a1, a2] in the database and seach by [a1, a3] we'll find a book. Instead, the exact match is necessary.

Comment: In this case `Criteria API` or `Specification` can be opted for. I have answered one more time

Answer (score 1):

If the exact match is necessary you can use `Specification` like this

```
public class BookSpecifications {
        public static Specification<Book> byAuthorsNames(List<String> names) {
            return (root, query, builder) -> {
                Join<Book, Author> author = root.join("authors", JoinType.LEFT);

                Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction;
                for(String name : names) {
                    Predicate namePredicate = builder.and(author.get("name"), name);
                    predicate = builder.and(predicate, namePredicate);
                }

                return predicate;
            }
        }
}
```

`BookRepository` have to extend `JpaSpecificationExecutor`.

Usage:

```
BookRepository repository;

public List<Book> findByAuthorsNames(List<String> names) {
    return repository.findAll(BookSpecifications.byAuthorsNames(names));
}
```

Comment: this converts into select book0_.id as id1_1_, book0_.name as name2_1_, book0_.visit_id as visit_id3_1_ from book book0_ left outer join book_authors authors1_ on book0_.id=authors1_.book_id left outer join author author2_ on authors1_.authors_id=author2_.id where 1=1 and author2_.name=? and author2_.name=?

Comment: Is the result as expected? Your SQL script contains database specific function ARRAY_AGG. There are no way to use it in JPQL statement. So you can get the same result using JPQL, but not the same SQL. You should use native query instead of JPQL